# Ajax is not getting data and starting the $_SESSION PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have two dropdowns where ajax gets the value from it and send to my page calculates.php and then i will get a result based on both dropdown selection.
But its not working well.
The problem is that im getting a error that is saying

**Notice: Undefined index: icms in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\cart.php on line 159**

**Notice: Undefined index: icms in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\cart.php on line 160**

icms is a variable that holds the $_SESSION['icms'].
When i get the result i must store in session and get data from data base.
I dont know why i am getting this.
And my values are not returning.
my script

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $('.fabric').on('change',function(e){
        var fabricID = $(this).val();
        console.log("fabric id_price is " + fabricID); //debugging
        if(fabricID){
           $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'calculates.php',
                data:'id_price='+fabricID,
                success:function(html){                                                          

                  // do nothing cuz i just need to combine with script bellow 
               //some closing tags

    $('.size').on('change',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        var sizeID = $(this).val();
        if(sizeID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'calculates.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:'size_id='+sizeID,

                success:function(html){
                  $(".icms" + id).text(data.val);
              //some closing tags
```

this is where i get my dropdown data and search database...
calculates.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once '../incluedes/conn_cms.php'; 

if(isset($_GET["size_id"],$_GET["id_price"])){
    $the_size=$_GET["size_id"] ;
    $the_id_price=$_GET["id_price"] ;


 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM valores_almofadas 
            WHERE size='$the_size' 
            AND   price_id ='$the_id_price'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'SP'){
  $ICMS = $rows['icms_7'];
  }else{
  $ICMS = $rows['icms_12'];
  }
  $_SESSION['icms']=$ICMS;

  } echo $_SESSION['icms'];

}
```

and here where i am supouse to receive data from the result.
this below is my cart.php script

`$value` holds quantity
and the `$id` holds the product row id.

**159**   `<td class="icms'.$id.'">R$:'.$_SESSION['icms'] .'</td>`

**160**   `<td class="total'.$id.'">'.$value * $_SESSION['icms'] .' </td>`

Comment: if your while() loop won't get executed then there won't be 'icms' at the $_SESSION

Comment: So my ajax  script is wrong?